# Consider a function $f$ continuous in $[a,b]$. It is known that $f(a)\cdot f(b) > 0$ How many zeros does the function have in that interval?

Tags: calculus

> Let $f$ be a real function of a real variable, continuous in $[a,b]$.
>
> It is known that $f(a) \cdot f(b) > 0$.
>
> Which of the following statements is correct?
>
> (A) Nothing can be concluded about the number of solutions of the
>   equation $f(0)$ in $[a,b]$.
>
> (B) The equation $f(x) = 0$ has one solution in $[a,b]$.
>
> (C) The equation $f(x) = 0$ has infinite solutions in $[a,b]$.
>
> (D) The equation $f(x) = 0$ has not solutions in $[a,b]$.

My book says the solution is (A) but I don't understand why.

If $f(a) \cdot f(b) > 0$, then that means that $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ have to be both either positive or negative and thus, if the sign doesn't change, there should be no solutions and (D) should be the correct answer.

Am I missing something? Why is (A) the right answer and not (D)?

Comment: Just draw different ones. You can see that you can have any number of roots, or none.

Comment: What about $x^2-1$ on $[-1.5,1.5]$?

Comment: @user363120 I see. D would only be correct if the function was injective, right?

Comment: Saying $f(a)f(b)>0$ says only that $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ have the same sign. Why should it imply whatever about the sign  in-between?

Comment: @MarkRead At least if $f$ is injective, then $(D)$ is true. That's probably what you meant, right? (You said that if $(D)$ is true, then $f$ is injective; which is false).

Comment: @user363120 Yes that's what I meant. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not too hard to come up with examples satisfying (B), (C), and (D).

- (B): Let $f(x) = 1+\cos x$ on $[0,2\pi]$.  Then $f(0) = f(2\pi) = 2$ and the only zero is at $\pi$.
- (C): Let
  $$
     f(x) = \begin{cases}
               1-x & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
                 0 & 1 \leq x \leq 2 \\
               x-2 & 2 \leq x \leq 3
            \end{cases}
  $$
  Then $f(0) = f(3) = 1$, but $f$ has infinitely many zeroes.
- (D): Let $f(x) = 1$ on $[0,1]$.  Then $f(0) = f(1) = 1$, but $f$ has no zeroes.

Since none of these are impossible, the only allowable answer is (A).

Comment: Just one thing, isn't $1+cos(\pi) = 0$? Do you mean (B) $f(x) = \cos(x)$? Otherwise, the only zero would be at $x = \pi$, not $x = \pi/2$

Comment: @MarkRead whoops! Let me rework that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also easily come up with a continuous function satisfying $f(a)f(b) > 0$ with any desired number of zeros in $[a,b]$ by setting
$$f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} (x - x_i)^2$$
for numbers $x_i \in (a,b)$.